# Sample a single color texture in metal

Tags: metal

Im trying to setup some monocolor textures. I want to use a texture composed of a single 32bit float. Then use a linear sampler to interpolate values from it. I have setup my metal texture descriptor as follows.

```c
MTLTextureDescriptor *textureDescriptor = [[MTLTextureDescriptor alloc] init];
textureDescriptor.textureType = MTLTextureType2D;
textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatR32Float;
textureDescriptor.width = width;
textureDescriptor.height = height;
textureDescriptor.depth = 1;
textureDescriptor.mipmapLevelCount = 1;
textureDescriptor.sampleCount = 1;
textureDescriptor.arrayLength = 1;
textureDescriptor.cpuCacheMode = MTLCPUCacheModeWriteCombined;
textureDescriptor.storageMode = MTLStorageModeManaged;
textureDescriptor.allowGPUOptimizedContents = true;
textureDescriptor.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead;
```

However I'm getting a compiling error in my shader code.

```cpp
kernel text_kernel(texture2d<float, access::sample> x [[texture(0)]])
{
    constexpr sampler linear(coord::normalized,
                             address::clamp_to_edge,
                             filter::linear);
    float x_sample = x.sample(linear, float2(0.1, 0.2));
}
```

It appears that sample wants to return a float4 instead of a single float. So this raises a number of questions.

## 1 What's being returned in the other three components?

Is it returning the neighboring pixels or just putting all the same value in the other components.

## 2 Is sample normalizing the pixel values?

If I initialize the texture with float values greater than 1 or less than zero is it clamping the sampled values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 What's being returned in the other three components?

I believe it fills the missing components from the corresponding component of `float4(0, 0, 0, 1)`.

If you're only interested in the red component, just apply `.r` to the result from `sample()`. I.e.:

```
    float x_sample = x.sample(linear, float2(0.1, 0.2)).r;
```

> 2 Is sample normalizing the pixel values?

No. For floating-point pixel formats, it doesn't clamp.

Comment: Does it do interpolation correctly?